# How to get various information about LVM objects in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, lvm

I want to automate some maintenance actions, and I need to be able to request some details about LVM objects in my scripts.

In particular, I need to be able to request at least the PE size in bytes and how many free PEs is available on the certain PV.

There is some progress, e.g. `pvdisplay --units b --nosuffix` shows data in bytes and without garbage.

However, I hoped that I won't be required to parse this output much (with grep/awk/etc.), and I can make `pvdisplay` and other LVM utilities to output exactly the data I need. I think that would be more robust. There is an option `-o`/`--options` which should filter the output, according to the `man pvdisplay`. The manual page also says that the list of available fields for use with `-o` could be obtained by running with `-o help`. Nevertheless, `-o help` and anything else with `-o` always outputs:

```
  Incompatible options selected
  Run `pvdisplay --help' for more information.
```

That's all. There is even a bug in Fedora bugzilla, closed without solution due to EOL of the version for which it was reported.

Is it possible to output only certain information, or should I resort to parsing a standard LVM output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{pv,lv,vg}display --options` parameter seems to only work in conjunction with `--columns`, equivalent to the shorthand `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs` commands.

> the PE size in bytes

```
# vgs -o vg_extent_size --units b VGNAME
```

> how many free PEs is available

```
# pvs -o pv_pe_count,pv_pe_alloc_count /dev/PV
```

or alternatively

```
# pvs -o pv_free --units b /dev/PV
```

If you don't want to specify the VG / PV directly, add `name` to the options.

There are additional options that might help with parsing, e.g. `--noheadings`, `--nosuffix`, `--separator=:`, `--rows`, `--quiet` or `--reportformat=json`. Yet another option would be to parse the output of `pvdisplay --colon`.

Comment: Nowhere it was said it has to be used like that! Anyway, thank you, that's what I was asking for, `pvs -o pv_free --noheadings --units b --nosuffix --separator= PV` (there's a space after "=") and friends do the trick.